# How Do I filter System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine in output window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

It seems that Visual Studio is not that smart in order to filter the output windows as Eclipse is....

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click in the output window (when it's active) and deselect everything but "Program output".